# Getting "Failed to update" message despite successful update

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfc

Using the jquery plugin http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/ with Coldfusion.

It was working great with a post to a CFM page, but when I moved my update to a CFC, I started getting a "Failed to update value" message despite the fact that the update succeeded.

Here is the jquery call:

```
<script>
  $("#editTitle").editInPlace({
    //url: "http://mydomain.com/edit_ref.cfm",
    url: "http://mydomain.com/cfcs/eh_utilities.cfc?method=updateTitle",
    hover_class: "theHover",
    params: "id=<cfoutput>#URL.id#</cfoutput>",
});
```

And the CFC:

```
<cffunction name="updateTitle" access="remote" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="id" required="yes" type="numeric"> 
    <cfargument name="update_value" required="yes" type="string"> 
    <cfquery name="qEditTitle" datasource="#application.datasource#">
        update eh_reference set title = '#update_value#' where id = #id#
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn update_value>
</cffunction>
```

As mentioned, the update succeeds, but I get a Javascript alert from in-place-edit after the update that states "Failed to update value".

Thanks!

Comment: First, use [**cfqueryparam**](http://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam)! Second, check the browser's console/net tab for actual response/errors.

Comment: Thanks Peter. The console revealed "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mydomain.com/cfcs/eh_utilities.cfc?method=updateTitle. Origin http://www.mydomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." I made the path to the CFC relative instead of absolute and the problem was solved.

Comment: Can you post and mark the answer? Thanks!